# How many diamonds can you find in one vein?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know the smallest is 1 diamond out from my own experience in finding diamonds, and I have found 11 in one vein once. Is this the largest vein that can possibly spawn?

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft generates 1 vein per chunk, but doesn't look at other chunks when doing so, so it is theoretically possible (but extremely unlikely) to find a "megavein" of 32 diamonds comprised of 4 adjacent 8-diamond veins on a chunk crossing. It's much more common to find 9-10 diamond "veins" as, say, a 4-diamond and a 6-diamond vein align along a chunk border.

Comment: What would be the chances of this?

Comment: @Diehe the base of finding diamonds is 0.0846%. So 0.0846 times it's self a cupple of times = 0.0000512249392656%. but it would be even lower then that because finding them next to eachother is even rarer so about 0.000000002623994%

Comment: Those are some pretty low odds. Do we know of anyone who has found anything close?

Comment: @Diehe most of the ones you find online are staged but i am sure you can find some that are not

Answer (score 2):

Updated to version 1.18, Caves and Cliffs:

> [Diamond](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_Ore#Natural_generation) ore attempts to generate in three batches:
>
> - The first batch generates 7 times per chunk in blobs of 0-5 ores, from Y=14 to Y=-63
> - The second batch generates in 1⁄9 chunks in blobs of 0-23 ores, from Y=14 to Y=-63
> - The third batch generates 4 times per chunk in blobs of 0-10 ores, from Y=14 to Y=-63

(Each one being more common as the y-level decreases.)

This means that you may eventually find a 23-diamond vein on a single chunk, with multiple 10-diamond veins on adjacent chunks. Making a grand total of **53 diamonds** for a single vein. Theoretically. This seems extremely unlikely, as @*Pink_killer2* suggested.